# OLS estimation of AR and BLUE

Tags: econometrics, time-series, autoregressive

Is it valid to apply OLS to the AR process?
I learn that there exist correlation between explanatory variables and error term in AR model. I'm wondering how can show that $E(u_t|1,y_1,y_2,...,y_{t-1})\ne0$

And if AR model can not satisfy the assumption of BLUE, why OLS still used to estimate coefficient of AR model?

Statistical proof would be greatly appreciated, and if not, an intuition would be enough.

Comment: Hi: what you want to show is that E($y_{t-1} \times u_s | u_s, u_{s-1}, \ldots, u_0$) doesn't equal zero  for some $s$ less than or equal to $(t-1)$.  Note that I wrote $y_{t-1}$ because $y_{t-1}$ is "X" in the AR(1). The expression you wrote equals zero so you won't be able to show that but that's not an OLS assumption.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But as far as I know conditional expectation of error should be equal to $0$ to OLS  satisfy BLUE. Denote vector of explanatory variables $X_t=(1 y_1 y_2 ... y_{t-1})$. Is it true that $E(u_t|X_t)=0$ in AR? It seems to be not, but I can't find obvious proof :(

Comment: Hi: The OLS and BLUE assumptions are sometimes written differently. Can you show where you saw that one because I'm not familiar with it. But, the point you make is true ( if you write (E($ X_t | u_s) s \le t$ )  for all $s < t$ ). It doesn't equal zero which is why AR can't be estimated using OLS. If you search in stats.stackexchange, there are many discussions of AR(1) being biased if one uses OLS.

Comment: Thank you. I will review some more existing questions about AR in stats.stackexchange.

Comment: good. if you're  not clear after that, send a comment and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Hi: One more thing. Th conditional expectation of $u_t$ should be zero but that's not the only assumption. There needs to be an assumption about the orthogonality of the error and the $X's$.

Comment: @markleeds, have you swapped $X$ with $u$ in your second comment? Otherwise, why would we ask for $X$ to be zero mean, conditionally or otherwise?

Comment: I should have written multiplication rather than conditional. my mistake but I can't fix it because it's a comment.

Comment: @user170085: If you have or can get "an introduction to econometric theory" by james davidson. It's quite a nice book and explains things in a very clear and simple way. Chapter 7 covers OLS assumptions and chapter 8 covers the Gauss Markov theorem. It's very much an introductory to econometrics type text but it's got all the linear algebra steps in it and none of  those "it is easy to see that" type statements.

Comment: @markleeds, I checked the book out, and it does not seem to contain anything about autoregression or autocorrelation (serial correlation). (I did not read the book, just searched for the relevant terms.) As such, it might be of limited relevance for someone interested in autoregression. But perhaps I overlooked something?

Comment: Hi Richard: I was referring to the OLS assumptions. When you have an AR(1), X in the usual OLS regression is $y_{t-1}$ so you just replace $X$ with $y_{t-1}$ and see if it satisfies the OLS assumptions. It doesn't.

Comment: oddly enough, I read the section on the assumptions in the book and it does not contain the orthogonality assumption. This is quite odd. I'll go on the net and see if I can find something. Thanks to Richard for pointing that out.

Comment: To user170085 and Richard. See the answer to this question. It has a nice explanation of the various assumptions that are needed. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349460/why-don-t-we-need-strict-exogeneity-for-ols-consistency. My apologies for confusion but I think that answer is pretty clear.